# Редирект на jQuery или javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать на jQuery или javascript.

При клике на любую href ссылку происходил переход на сайт "site.ru".

Comment: <a href="site.ru">Редирект на jQuery или javascript</a>

Comment: @adwnix, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

```
for(i=0; i < document.links.length; i++)

{
    document.links[i].href = 'http://site.ru';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#">Редирект на jQuery или javascript</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
      $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    window.location.replace("http://site.ru");
   });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант [[@jackrv](/users/16784/jackrv)](/users/16784/jackrv) мне больше нравится, но если нужно на jquery, то вот [работающий вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/30v4bk6r/1/).

Comment: Однако мой Вариант не соответствует задаче (понял не сразу). Требовалось задать обработчик кликам по ссылкам, а не заменить их ***href***, хоть и в данной ситуации это равнозначные действия!